# Is there a way to actually use same port number for two different applications?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port, virtualization

I actually was working on Vmware and MySql, But they both use the same port 3306. So now one application runs and the other doesn't until I change the configuration of the other. Now my question is could we use buffer software and assign an id to each application and load balance the data across two applications by using the same port number?
Is it practical?. If so could anyone help me out on how to build a program that analyses the same port numbers of two applications and performs load balancing? Is there any python library that I could use to solve this problem?

Comment: No, this isn't really possible. When a connection comes in, how would the software know which application should receive it?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can deploy 2 docker containers and map different ports `-p output_port1: 3306` and `-p output_port_2:3306`

Comment: Also for load balancing, both the services should be identical (ex: copy od same server). But Vmware and MySql does not seem to same service

Comment: You should be able to assign a virtual IP to the VMWare container, and MySQL would only listen on the real IP.

Comment: This can be done, but it needs some middleware or collaboration of the services to first receive and then decide what to do with the connection; for example https://pfsense-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vpn/openvpn/sharing-a-port-between-openvpn-and-a-web-server.html

Comment: [sf] might be a better place to ask about this.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking this is doable, but unpractical and I wouldn’t recommend it. 

The solution is simple. You can do DNAT for 3306 based on source IP, source port or (I THINK) even based on ToS fields.